# Task Parallel Library and PLINQ Alternatives in C#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, libraries, plinq, parallel-processing

I am wondering what alternatives there are to the TPL and PLINQ in terms of libraries of collections designed for exploiting parallelism in C#.

EDIT: As phrased I think the question was confusing. I am looking for parallel collection libraries other than PLINQ. Possibly implemented on top of PLINQ and the TPL. I'm especially interested in pure functional libraries.

Comment: What is it about the TPL that you are finding dissatisfying?

Comment: Does reactive extesions count?

Comment: @JaredPar I don't mean to imply that the TPL is unsatisfactory, but I would like to know what other options there are. But since you ask: the TPL is a bit too low-level for some purposes and I disagree with some of the design decisions made in PLINQ (e.g. conflation of sequences and unordered collections).

Comment: @DerekBeattie The RX library serves a very different purpose than the parallel framework.

Comment: @cdiggins true but there is some overlap, things you can do with TPL that you can accomplish with Rx unless I'm confusing the new async stuff with plain TPL.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Concurrency and Coordination Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb905470.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Parallelism always involves multiple threads (or computers! thats the thing not covered in them :) ) to run the same task. It's quite easy to equally divide a set of input values and start a number of threads that each process one of these chunks. A bonus would be being able to read the results / exceptions from the calling thread. This is possible in both TPL and PLINQ.

The benefit of TPL and PLINQ is that you don't have to think about these details to make your task run in parallel. After you have made your program work, you can tweak how these libraries handle the input and output, with nearly no changes at all to your code. For instance you may not want to feed each thread with an equal amount of input values, but feed them with portions each time they finish a chunk.

I wouldn't really know what's missing, unless you're not really after true parallelism.

Comment: Thanks for answering but this is not what I was after. I'm looking for an alternative library to PLINQ and TPL for performing concurrent operations on collections. Sorry for my lack of clarity.

Comment: On one hand you want an alternative without explaining what you don't like about TPL/PLINQ, on the other you want something possibly implemented on top of PLINQ/TPL (which cannot count as "alternative"). Could you give an example of what you're looking for?